# Migrate Solr 1.4 index files to 4.7

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I had many problems when creating new collection in Solr 4.7 for an old 1.4 index. Finally I stuck with the following issue:

> Error CREATEing SolrCore 'newsarchive4': Unable to create core:
>   newsarchive4 Caused by: Format version is not supported (resource:
>   MMapIndexInput(path="E:\news-archive\data\newsarchive\index_4p.fdx")):
>   1 (needs to be between 2 and 3). This version of Lucene only supports
>   indexes created with release 3.0 and later.

[image]

How could I able to optimize or update the index file(s) to be compatible with Solr 4.7?

I have no any xml files of the documents, it is just the files in the dataDir.

**EDIT**
I tried the solution in femtoRgon comment but it returns the following error:

```
E:\solr-new\example\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib>java -cp lucene-core-4.7.2.jar org.apache.lucene.ind
ex.IndexUpgrader -delete-prior-commits -verbose E:\news-archive\data\newsarchive\index
IW 0 [Fri Aug 22 19:59:03 CEST 2014; main]: init: hit exception on init; releasing write lock
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException: Format version is not su
pported (resource: MMapIndexInput(path="E:\news-archive\data\newsarchive\index\_4p.fdx")): 1 (needs to
be between 2 and 3). This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 3.0 and later.
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene3x.Lucene3xStoredFieldsReader.checkCodeVersion(Lucene3xStored
FieldsReader.java:120)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene3x.Lucene3xSegmentInfoReader.readLegacyInfos(Lucene3xSegmentI
nfoReader.java:74)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:369)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:404)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:843)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:694)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:400)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:746)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader.upgrade(IndexUpgrader.java:161)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexUpgrader.main(IndexUpgrader.java:74)
```

Comment: You could try lucene's [`IndexUpgrader`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html)

Comment: @femtoRgon Please check the question's edit.

Comment: @sємsєм As femtoRgon wrote in his question; your version of IndexUpgrader is too recent. You'll have to grab an older version (otherwise Solr would do this for you anyway, since it upgrades the index files if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene 4.X appears to no longer support reading 1.X at all.  In order to upgrade it, I believe you will need to make it a two-step process, by first downloading Lucene 3.x, and using it to upgrade (using [`IndexUpgrader`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html)).

Once you have the index in a Lucene 3 format, you should be able to read and upgrade it with 4.7.

Comment: However, it should be Solr 3.5. I started with Solr 3.1 and this method does not exist in its api.

Comment: I got the same error as well. Apparently you can't migrate index from 4.0 to 4.7 too.